# Excel Data Analysis ToolPak available for download for Microsoft Office for Mac 2011?

Tags: ms-office

Does anyone know how to download the data analysis toolpack add-in for Excel 2011 for Mac? I have looked around quite a bit and can't seem to find it anywhere... did Microsoft discontinue this completely?

P.s. I am familiar with the [StatPlus software](http://www.analystsoft.com/en/products/statplusmac/) and have used it - that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for the native Data Analysis Toolpak for excel.

Comment: Is it any updates for this subject? Really need Data Analysis for 2011 mac! Grrrrrrr… Microsoft

Comment: @HenrikHenriksen This question might get stuck at Q: "Where is product X?" A: "It's gone" I'd love for you or anyone else to ask a separate linked question about what package for Excel does A, B, and C and explicitly list some data analysis items it needs to do.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it appears to have been discontinued.  Sorry.

Refer to the discussion at [What happened to the Data Analysis Toolpak or Solver in Excel for Mac 2011? – answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/what-happened-to-the-data-analysis-toolpak-or/740ff33a-6ed9-4553-bc09-5cef06ce5f23). Quote:

> **The Data Analysis Toolpak was removed in Office for Mac 2008.** *[emphasis mine]* However,
>   the following is a free third-party tool [...]
>
> *[... goes on to mention the StatPlus software you already mentioned ...]*

See also: [I can't find the Analysis ToolPak – Microsoft Office Mac Troubleshooting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/I-cant-find-the-Analysis-ToolPak-d678dc08-bdc2-4eda-8b94-08755fa4b55a). Quote:

> **Cause:** Excel 2011 does not include the Analysis ToolPak.
>
> **Solution:** Download StatPlus:mac LE for free from AnalystSoft, and then use StatPlus:mac LE with Excel 2011.
>   ...

That last link used to include loads of comments from disgruntled Office for Mac users, but Microsoft seems to have removed comment functionality from that help center article. Surely you can find disgruntled comments re: the above elsewhere on the net.